# "Elif" statements are not working properly

Tags: python

I am having some issues. In my code, I am to writing a "turing test" for diagnosing patients. 1. I really think this is more simple than I am writing it. 2. I'm not even doing this right. When I run the program, I keep getting the first options, no matter what I choose. 3. I cannot seem to make my program stop running. I've tried quit, break, exit, sys.exit, sys.exit(), and sys.exit(0). So my questions are: "Is there an easier way to do this?", "What am I doing wrong with my if and elif statements?", and "How do I make the program end when the user does not wish to continue?" Thanks!

(my program is not done yet, but you get the idea)

```
import sys

def doctor():

    print ("Welcome to medical diagnostics")
    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
    if ("Head"):
        raw_input ("Where does your head hurt? Scalp, Eyes, Nose, Cheeks, Ears, Mouth, Jaw, or none: ")
        if ("Scalp"):
            raw_input ("Are you experiencing Agitation, Bleeding, Fracturing, Bruising, Drainage, Fainting, Fever, Headaches, Migraines, Lumps, Lightheadedness, Dizziness, Swelling, or Seizures?: ")
            if ("Agitation"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to withdrawals, side effects of intoxication, side effects of methamphetamine use, dementia in head injury, or epilepsy. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Bleeding"):
                raw_input ("You may have had some sort of trauma or injury. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Fracturing"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that you are dealing with physical abuse, trauma or injury, or osteogenesis imperfecta. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Bruising"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to a contusion, a hematoma, trauma or injury, botox injections, or thrombocytopenia. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Drainage"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to an allergic reaction or one or several abscesses. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Fainting"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to a heart rhythm disorder, atrial or aortal complications, heat exhaustion, low blood pressure, anemia, ADHD, dehydration, drug overdose, hyperventilation, low blood sugar, lyme disease, pulmonary embolism or hypertension, or a brain aneurysm. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Fever"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to viral pharyngitis, acute sinusitis, influenza, bacterial pneumonia, gastroenteritis, middle ear infection, sunburn, urinary tract infection, meningitis, coxsackie virus infection, one or several abscesses, aspirin poisoning, borchial adenoma, Crohn's disease, cryptococcosis, drug overdose, drug withdrawals, epiglottitis, hepatitis A or B, inflammatory bowel disease, kidney infection, lupus, lyme disease, mononucleosis, mumps, osteomyelitis, pericarditis, phlebitis, rheumatic fever, rheumatoid arthritis, sarcoidosis, scarlet fever, syphilis, thalassemia, thyroid storm, tuberculosis, valley fever, viral pneumonia, histoplasmosis, sickle cell disease, tick bite, brain infection, Chagas disease, dengue fever, legionella, malaria, toxic shock syndrome, typhoid fever, whooping cough, pilonidal cysts, measles, mesenteric lymphadenitis, plague, shingles, west nile virus, anthrax, endocarditis, or cat-scratch disease. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Headaches"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to tension, acute sinusitis, acute stress reaction, caffeince withdrawals, type 1 or 2 diabetes, excessive caffeine use, malocclusion, nearsighedness, postconcussive syndrome, sleep apnea, sunburn, chronic sinusitis, meningitis, allergic reactions, anemia, astigmatism, botox injections, carbon monoxide poisoning, cervical spondylosis, chronic kidney disease, coxsackie virus infection, cryptococcosis, dementia in head injury, head injury, heat exhaustion, high blood pressure, hypocalcemia, insulin reaction, intracranial hematoma, lupus, lyme disease, mononucleosis, multiple sclerosis, mumps, nasal polyps, nonallergic rhinitis, noroviruses, ocular migraine, sporotrichosis, thalassemia, constipation, chemical burns, tick bite, anemia, brain aneurysm, brain infection, cyanide poisoning, endocarditis, lead poisoning, plague, pseudohypoparathyroidism, radiation sickness, typhoid fever, osteomyelitis, bird flu, brain tumor, shingles, or west nile virus. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Migraines"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to a brain aneurysm or meningitis. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Lumps"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to trauma or injury, abscesses, epidermal cysts, or benign lipoma. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Lightheadedness"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to generalized anxiety disorder, heart rhythm disorder, hyperventilation, supraventricular tachycardia, acute kidney failure, anemia, heart complications, high or low blood pressure, labyrinthitis, thalassemia, or toxic shock syndrome. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Dizziness"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to middle ear infection, labyrinthitis, benign paroxysmal positional vertigo, diabetes, fainting, generalized anxiety disorder, heart rhythm disorder, panic attack, anemia, heart complications, aspirin poisoning, benzodiazepine abuse, carbon monoxide poisoning, cryptococcosis, dehydration, heat exhaustion, high or low blood pressure, hyperventilation, insulin reaction, Meniere's disease, pulmonary hypertension, supraventricular tachycardia, chemical burns, anemia, cyanide poisoning, or small intestine cancer. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Swelling"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to bee or wasp stings, insect bites or stings, poison ivy, oak, or sumac, burns, chemical burns, or osteomyelitis. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("Seizures"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to alcohol withdrawal, cocaine abuse, insulin reaction, barbiturate abuse, brain aneurysm, brain infection, brain tumor, Chigas disease, tetanus, or west nile virus. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("none"):
                raw_input ("Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
        if ("Eyes"):
            raw_input ("Are you experiencing Bleeding, Blurred Vision, Fracturing, Bruising, Double Vision, Drainage, Redness, Floating Spots, Scratchy Eyes, Irritation, Lumps, Bruising, Numbness, Red Eyelid, Swelling, or none?: ")
            if ("Bleeding"):
                raw_input ("You may have had some sort of trauma or injury. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("blurred vision"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to Diabetes, Eye injury, Nearsightedness, Pink eye, Acute angle-closure glaucoma, Astigmatism, Benzodiazepine abuse, Cryptococcosis, Diabetic ketoacidosis, Epilepsy, Foreign object in the eye, Glaucoma, Low blood pressure, Ocular migraine, Retinal detachment, Diabetic eye disease, or Pseudohypoparathyroidism. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("fracturing"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to a broken eye socket. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("bruising"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to a hematoma, black eye, botox injection, trauma or injury, or thrombocytopenia. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("double vision"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to diabetes, alcohol intoxication, aspirin poisoning, cataracts, botulinum poisoning, or Cavernous sinus thrombosis. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("drainage"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to pink eye or one or several abscesses. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("floating spots"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to benign eye floaters, diabetic disease, or retinal detachment. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("scratchy eyes"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to Dust exposure, Hay fever, Pink eye, Wind exposure, Dry eyes, Foreign object in the eye, Sarcoidosis, Sjogren's syndrome, or Bird flu. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("irritation"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to Allergic reaction, Indoor allergens, Hay fever, Rosacea, Eye allergies, or Chagas disease. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("lumps"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to one or several abscesses or chalzion. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("numbness"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to burns or chemical burns. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("swelling"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to Acute sinusitis, Allergic reaction, Hay fever, Pink eye, Bee or wasp stings, Eye allergies, Foreign object in the eye, Insect bites, Insect sting, Poison ivy, oak, or sumac, Burn, or Chemical burns. Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("none"):
                raw_input ("Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
        if ("Nose"):
            raw_input ("Are you experiencing bruising, difficulty breathing, drainage, congestion, nosebleed, numbness, pain, swelling, tenderness, or none?: ")
            if ("bruising"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("difficulty breathing"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("drainage"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("congestion"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("nosebleed"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("numbness"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("pain"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("swelling"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("tenderness"):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
            elif ("none"):
                raw_input ("Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
        if ("Cheeks"):
            raw_input ("")
            elif (""):
                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
                if ("Yay"):
                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
                elif ("Nay"):
                    sys.exit(0)
        if ("Ears"):
            raw_input ("")
        if ("Mouth"):
            raw_input ("")
        if ("Jaw"):
            raw_input ("")
        if ("None"):
            raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
    if ("Neck"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Chest"):
        raw_input ("Where does your chest hurt? Sternum, Chest, or Lateral: ")
        if ("Sternum"):
            raw_input ("")
        if ("Chest"):
            raw_input ("")
        if ("Lateral"):
            raw_input ("")
    if ("Abdomen"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Back"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Arms"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Legs"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Buttocks"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("Pelvis"):
        raw_input ("")
    if ("None"):
        raw_input ("Do you have a fever? Y or N: ")
        if ("Y"):
            raw_input ("Are you feeling nauseous? Yes or No: ")
            if ("Yes"):
                raw_input ("")
            if ("No"):
                raw_input ("")
        if ("N"):
            raw_input ("")


doctor()
#       elif (""):
#                raw_input ("It is possible that this is due to . Would you like to start over? Yay or Nay: ")
#                if ("Yay"):
#                    raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: ")
#                elif ("Nay"):
#                    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: When using raw input, you need to store the response in a variable, then compare that. For example `answer = raw_input('What hurts?')`. You can then compare this with other strings, for example `if answer == 'head'):`. Right now, you're evaluating the truth value of strings, which are always true, unless empty.

Comment: Might I suggest adding a variable to hold the text "Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: " so you do not repeat it 100 times in the code?

Comment: You might want to look at decision trees...

Answer (score 5):

All of your conditionals, as you have them, will evaluate to `True` because you're evaluating the "truthiness" of the **strings** `"Head"`, `"Scalp"` and so on. What you want is to compare those strings to the results of your input requests.

```
area = raw_input ("Which area hurts? Head, Neck,...") 
if area == "Head":
    head_area = raw_input("Where does your head hurt?...")
    # etc
else:
    # etc
```

---

As for "am I doing this right", your logic seems to be sound at a glance. However, there are certainly **easier** ways to do what you're doing. My simplest thought would be to use a dictionary to hold all your possible diagnosis paths: think of this like a "tree" (in fact I recommend drawing a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) if you haven't already done so). You can then embed the "tree" in a Python dictionary and simply use the dictionary keys to fill in your template strings (`"Which area hurts? ..."` and `"It is possible that..."`).

A very brief example of what I mean:

```
# First, design your diagnosis tree. This will hold all the real logic.
diagnosis_tree = {
    'head' : { # first "level"
        'scalp' : { # second "level"
            'bleeding' : 'trauma or injury', # condition and diagnosis
            'agitation' : 'withdrawals, intoxication, dementia, or epilepsy'
        }
    },
    'chest' : {
        'sternum' : {
            'bleeding' : 'shot in the chest'
        }
    }
}

# Now, just traverse the tree according to the user input.

# Get first "level"
area = raw_input('Which area hurts?\n' + 
                 '\n'.join(k for k in diagnosis_tree))
area_tree = diagnosis_tree.get(area) # look up first level in the tree.

# Get second level of detail
sub_area = raw_input('Where does your {0} hurt?\n'.format(area) + 
                     '\n'.join(k for k in area_tree))
sub_area_tree = area_tree.get(sub_area) # look up second level in the tree.

# Get condition
condition = raw_input('What are you experiencing?\n' + 
                      '\n'.join(k for k in sub_area_tree))
diagnosis = sub_area_tree.get(condition) # look up condition in the tree.

# Print the final diagnosis
print('This could be due to {0}'.format(diagnosis))
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! Thank you for showing me some more efficient methods! Also, once I correct myself and hold values, do I use exit or sys.exit?

Comment: @TravisJ.Land For your purposes (and most purposes, honestly), they are exactly the same. [See the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) for (a little) more detail. However, if you want to keep looping until the user wants to exit, it might be simpler to just place the whole user-interaction flow inside a `while True:`, and then `break` when the user wants to quit.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the input with `raw_input()` but you are not storing the user feed!
You should store that value & then do an `if`...`else` on it.

Something, like below

```
area = raw_input("Where does it hurt?")
if area == "chest":
    # do/ask something related to chest
elif area == "neck":
    # do/ask something related to neck
...
else:
    print ("Please specify one of these - chest/neck/...")
```

Also, you could just store the questions into variables in the beginning & then use them by the variables, so that your code looks more nice.

```
ques_area = "Which area hurts? Head, Neck, Chest, Abdomen, Back, Arms, Legs, Buttocks, Pelvis, or none: "
ans_area = raw_input(ques_area)
```